# Solving logic game Lights out with A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, lua, a-star

I have some problems solving the logic puzzle called Lights out using the A* algorithm. For now, I'm using an implementation of the A* algorithm where I consider the entire matrix of lights as a node in the algorithm (where 1 represents the lights on and 0 the lights off), together with the coordinates of the current node that will be toggled. After I select the node from the open list with the lowest f score, I will toggle it and get its 8 adjacent neighbors and then append them to the open list and repeat until I find a node that has the sum of all the lights equals to 0 (all the lights are off).

For calculating the f score of each node, I simply compute the sum of all the lights in their local matrix, thus selecting every time the node which has the matrix with the lowest number of lights on.

I know that the algorithm will be not so performant, even when compared to the "Chasing the Lights" method, but I do not understand how to tell the algorithm which next node to pick, so which f scoring function to use, because considering the sum of the lights in the matrix will end up with the algorithm looping through the same 3/4 nodes every time.

Also, I would like some suggestions on how to represent a node for the algorithm since I can't get how to use an algorithm used generally for path optimization inside a matrix where you have a goal node, used in a situation like this where you consider the entire matrix as the node and your goal is not reaching a particular node but just checking that its sum is 0.

The language that I implemented all the work is Lua.

Thank you.

EDIT 5/27/19
Since I'm new to Lua, I'm blaming my mistakes and my capability of writing code in it and also my understanding of the algorithm to the fact that I'm not able to find the solution.
I wasn't good at explaining the problem I was having so I tried to get the best from the comments I received and now I will post the modified code so that guys if you want to help, you will understand better (code >> words haha).

Note: I wrote the algorithm based on this article [A* algorithm](https://medium.com/@nicholas.w.swift/easy-a-star-pathfinding-7e6689c7f7b2)

[lua source code](https://github.com/VincenzoNucci/lights-out-lua/blob/master/progetto.lua)

Comment: What do you mean by "*...will end up with the algorithm looping through the same 3/4 nodes every time*"? A* will never visit the same node a second time. Btw, it would help a lot if you could add details about the rules of the game. How do you decide what light in a matrix to toggle?

Comment: I suggest `f = 9 + (sum of all the lights in their local matrix)` where 9 is maximal number of light you can turn on/off during one step.

Comment: To implement A* correctly, you should put next node with its f(node) into a priority queue.  A node should be just a matrix, without "current cell".

Comment: If you're solving the 5x5 puzzle, then you can model the puzzle as a graph with 2^25 nodes, where each node has 25 neighbors.

Comment: If I do not consider also the current cell but just the matrix, how do I decide which will be the neighbors of that node?

Comment: You always has as many neighbors as the number of cells in a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for.

First of all, simple observation: each field in your game board you want to toggle at most once (toggling a field two times doesn't do anything).

You can go with a very bad approach and create 2^n game states (nodes in your graph), where n is amount of fields in your game board. Why is it terrible? It would take you at least O(2^n) time and space to just create the graph. In O(2^n) time you can just check all possible moves (since you want to toggle each board once) and just immidiately tell the result instead of running additional A*.

Better idea(?): Let's not phisically create the whole graph. You don't want to visit a node two times, so you should store somewhere (probably as some set of bitmasks, where you'd be able to check if a node is already in the set quickly) already visited nodes. Then, when you're in some node, you check all your neighbours - game states after toggling one field. If they're visited, ignore them, otherwise add them to your priority queue. Then take the first node from priority queue, remove it and 'go' to a game state it is representing.

As I said, you can represent game state as bitmask of size n - 0 on i-th position if i-th field hasn't been toggled, 1 otherwise.

Will that be better than naive approach? Depends on your heuristic function. I have no idea which one is better, you have to try some and check the results. In worst case your A* will check every nodes, making the complexity worse than simple brute force. If you get lucky, it may significantly speed it up.